# cssClass for ActionSheetController ionic 3

Tags: sass, ionic3

In my ionic 3 app ActionSheetController I have added buttons with icons. I am trying to modify the style by giving the icons color.

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: 'Upload Photo',
      cssClass: 'asheet'
      buttons: [
        {
          cssClass: 'button-cam'
          icon: 'camera',
          text: 'Take Picture',
          handler: () => {
            this.openCamera(from);
          }
        }, {
          icon: 'image',
          text: 'Photo Galary',
          handler: () => {
            this.openGalary(from);
          }
        }
        , {
          icon: 'close',
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Now I have added the two classes in my .scss files of the page.

```
.asheet{
 background: red;
}


.button-cam{
  background: red;
  icon{
    color: blue;
   }
  }
```

None of the styles are reflecting in the action sheet. Everything is black.

Comment: Where do you put the css?

Comment: I use the css for my HTML  page.

Comment: where have you given the css class if you have not given in .button-cam then make sure you place in there @TapasMukherjee

Comment: Sorry but I am a bit lost here. So I have 1 HTML file, its TS file and its CSS file. My code for Action Sheet in in the TS file and I have coded the class .asheet and .button-cam in the CSS file. Please let me know what needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

try put your css into app.scss, not in the page.scss

```
.myPage {
    .myActionSheetBtnStyle {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

and then using the style in your actionSheet

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
    title: 'title',
    cssClass: 'myPage',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Action',
            cssClass: 'myActionSheetBtnStyle',
            handler: () => {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this work with Ionic 4 +? Isn't working for me